# Python: Message error when using bgpic() from turtle module

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to change the background image in a turtle window.

The code reads simply as this:

```
import turtle
turtle.bgpic("france53.gif")
```

The turtle window shows up blank and I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-25-45373f8f3ea2>", line 1, in <module>
bgpic("france53.gif")

File "<string>", line 1, in bgpic

File "/Users/danielcharrier/anaconda/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 1482, in bgpic
self._setbgpic(self._bgpic, self._bgpics[picname])

File "/Users/danielcharrier/anaconda/lib/python3.4/turtle.py", line 738, in _setbgpic
self.cv.itemconfig(item, image=image)

File "<string>", line 1, in itemconfig

File "/Users/danielcharrier/anaconda/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2416, in itemconfigure
return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)

File "/Users/danielcharrier/anaconda/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1310, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))

TclError: image "pyimage12" doesn't exist
```

The file "france53.gif" is in the working directory. What should I do to make it work?

I'm using the Anaconda distribution for Mac OS X.

Thanks!